# How to implement jquery-ui autocomplete with asp.net and json?

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm studying asp.net and jquery, right now I'm trying to implement a simple autocomplete in PHP I was able to do something like this:

Here's the client code:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.auto').autocomplete(
            {
                source: "search.php", 


                focus: function(event, ui) {
        $(idField).val(ui.item.value);
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },

                select: function(event, ui) {
        //$(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        var a = "#"+$(this).attr('id');

        $(a+"hidden").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }
                //minLength: 3
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here's my code that does the searching:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "isproj2"; 

// open connection 
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 

// select database 
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);


$query = "Select SupplierName, SupplierID from tbl_supplier where SupplierName LIKE '%$text%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = array();

$first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = array('label' => $row['SupplierName'], 'value' => $row['SupplierID']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

What I want to happen is do something like this asp.net, In some articles I've read that I need to use a web service.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery autocomplete only needs a json object that it uses to fill in the possible values. It does not matter how it is generated on the server. You could indeed use a formal webservcie and I guess asp.net has very neat ways to generate those. I am no expert though.

As long as the response that is returned from your asp.net code is similar to the response of the php code the autocomplete will work.